# React reverse engineering facebook / messenger chat input

Tags: facebook, reactjs, input, chat, messenger

I'm trying to recreate with React the chat input of facebook / messenger. 
Until now, I understand that the chat input is a custom input for typing messages build with a `<div />` where the attribute contentEditable set to true. This custom input grows up with a min-height to a maximum height. 
Once the maximum height is reached, the custom input set a scrollbar to scroll his content.

I'm trying to figure out how this is handled with props of the custom input and the state of his mother component but I don't really see how to do it properly.

Is there a way, a tutorial or something else to do it ? Or to have good behaviours of the chat input ?

Comment: You could use CSS for min and max height constraints. You can also use the overflow property in CSS to set it to scroll on longer messages. You should have a state that stores the text inside the input field. Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it's a hard component to make because it's a CMS component (can handle html inputs). You should look at the actual component, `draft.js`, which is a CMS open sourced project. Pretty cool stuff.

Comment: Maybe you should look at Facebook's actual rich text editor, Draft.js - https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/

Comment: aashah7, Yeah you understand correctly :) 
ZekeDroid, Jeff McCloud Thanks you very much I will try Draft.js :)